# How to parse JSON data form URL?

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

Hi I am trying to parse json data from URL using basic Auth. The data comes from the server.

```
 HttpHost target = new HttpHost(targetUrl, 443, "https");
     HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, Integer.valueOf(proxyPort), "http");
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(5000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000)
      .setProxy(proxy).setAuthenticationEnabled(true).build();
     HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(targetURI + orderId + "/prod.json");
     httpget.setConfig(config);
response = httpClient.execute(target, httpget);
System.out.println(" Response ::" + EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```

It display the json data like

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "order_id": 100,
    "product_id": 113,
    "order_address_id": 1,
    "name": "Paper 002",
  }
]
```

And I have a pojo class of this Json data also.But when I am trying to read the display data it throws error.I use jackson for reading that data The code for reading data is.

```
String jsondata = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
               ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
     ProDesc pd = objMapper.readValue(jsondata, ProDesc.class);
    System.out.println("** ID " + pd.getId());
```

So how can I parse the data using the jackson? where I have the json data already display using above code.

Comment: Does your class ProDesc having attribute name same as that coming in Json ?

Comment: Yes I have same attribute name as comming json @kedarkamthe

Comment: What does your `ProDesc` class looks like?

Comment: @Narcis  My pojo class is like :public class MyPojo
{ private int id; and getter setter}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deserialize a list of `ProDesc` objects because your main JSON is an array.

This is how I deserialize something similar with Jackson 2.1.4:

```
List<ProDesc> proDescList = objMapper.readValue(jsondata, objMapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(List.class, ProDesc.class));
```

**EDIT**: If your `ProDesc` class contains only the `id` member, you need to tell Jackson to ignore the other members with an annotation like so:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class ProDesc {

    private int id;

    public ProDesc(){}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just posted code that worked for me in that specific version. Of course there may be other ways to do it. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I used  this code to solve this problem

```
 List<ProdDesc> proDescList = objMapper.readValue(jsondata, new TypeReference<List<ProDes>>() { }); 
for(ProDesc produ:proDescList)
{ System.out.println(produ.getId()); }
```